# use Exponential smoothing to forecast lead-time demand

Tags: forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I'd like to use Simple Exponential smoothing to forecast the lead-time demand for inventory
control, I have monthly data and LT+1 is equal to 5 months, can I do a forecast using SES which gives me a one-period-ahead forecast and then multiply it by 5  to get the forecast for LT+1 ?
what is the best solution to get h step ahead forecast(like LT+1)when the forecast method is SES?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for Single Exponential Smoothing, the lead time demand (which is the sum of the forecasts over the lead time) is necessarily a simple multiple of a one-step-forecast.

If you use a more complex model (with seasonality and/or trend), this will of course not hold any more. In addition, you will need to think about safety stocks and quantile forecasts.

I recommend [this free online textbook on forecasting](http://otexts.com/fpp/).